# Redux/React. After implement the combineReducers cannot get state of app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

After combining two `reducers` together (`EditButton` and `TodoApp`), my app everytime start crash. Before it, when I just use only one reducer `TodoApp` I did not have any problem with `reducers`. But now I cannot figure out what is wrong, because every time I get the error in `map` function of `component` below . Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

So, what is I forgot? Also I cannot get the state in nested components or containers of `App`. It's strange too, but in `App` I can do that by console.log() for example.

/* REDUCERS */

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TODO, EDIT_TODO, DELETE_TODO, FILTER_TODO_UP, FILTER_TODO_DOWN } from '../Variables/Variables'

const initialState = {
    todos: []
}

function EditButton(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 'Edit';
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case EDIT_TODO:
            return state = "Edit" ? "Done" : "Edit"
        default:
            return state
    }
}

function TodoApp(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initialState;
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: [
                    ...state.todos, 
                    {
                        id: action.id,
                        text: action.text,
                        done: action.done
                    }
                ]
            });
        case EDIT_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: [
                    ...state.todos, 
                    {
                        id: action.id,
                        text: action.text,
                        done: action.done
                    }
                ]
            });
        case DELETE_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, {
                todos: state.todos.filter(todos => todos.id !== parseInt(action.id))
            });
        case FILTER_TODO_UP:
            return Object.assign({}, {
                todos: [
                ...state.todos.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
                ]
            });
        case FILTER_TODO_DOWN:
            return Object.assign({}, {
                todos: [
                    ...state.todos.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
                ]
            });
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}



export default combineReducers({TodoApp, EditButton})
```

/* APP */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import TodoFormAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormAdd';
import TodoListAdd from '../Containers/TodoListAdd';
import TodoFormFilterAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormFilterAdd';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
                // console.log(this.props.state.getState()) - work!
                <TodoFormAdd />
                <TodoListAdd store={this.props.store} />
                <TodoFormFilterAdd />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

/* CONTAINER */

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from '../Components/TodoList/TodoList';
import { DeleteTodo } from '../Actions/AddTodo'

// console.log(this.props.state.getState()) - does not work!

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: state.todos
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      todoFormDelete: todo => dispatch(DeleteTodo(todo))
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)
```

/* COMPONENT */

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoIteam from '../TodoIteam/TodoIteam'

class TodoList extends React.Component {
handleDelete = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let closestDelete = target.closest('span');
    let closestEdit = target.closest('button');

    if (closestDelete) {
        let index = closestDelete.parentNode.getAttribute('index');
        this.props.todoFormDelete(index);
    } else { 
        return 
    }
}

render(props) {
// console.log(this.props.state.getState()) - does not work!

    return (
        <ul onClick={this.handleDelete}>{this.props.todos.map((iteam, index) => 
 // this where I get an error
                <TodoIteam key={index} index={iteam.id} {...iteam} />
            )}
        </ul>
    );
}
}

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are using ES6 property shorthand notation in `combineReducers` :

`combineReducers({TodoApp, EditButton})`

This is equivalent to writing `combineReducers({ TodoApp: TodoApp, EditButton: EditButton })`

But inside your CONTAINER you are accessing `state.todos` there is nothing called `todos` coming from state instead its `TodoApp` and Hence you get **error** in your `.map()`:

```
this.props.todos.map((iteam, index) {}
```

EDIT : 
As you are returning an object containing an array from your reducers called `todos` so to access correct state you need to use reducer Name followed by an array name you are returning which would be `TodoApp.todos`

So inside your Container you need to access correct `reducer`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: state.TodoApp.todos // Notice TodoApp is used instead of todos
});
```

You can read more about combineReducers on [Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers)

Comment: Thank you, but this is does not work. I change the container as you showed above. But nothing happen. Also I make the second try and  change `todos` in the component, like `this.props.TodoApp.map((iteam, index) =>`, but also without result...

Also I saw the Redux official docs, but in them said only about direct work with the combineReducer state, not for the real word app

Comment: In the above code I can not see you passing any `props` to your `COMPONENT` , where is this `this.props.todos` coming from ?

Comment: it coming from `container` above - `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: state.todos
});`

Comment: Oh, I understand what is the problem is. You give me a good aiming. We just need to upgrade you solution and make todos: `state.TodoApp.todos`, insted of `todos: state.TodoApp`. I do not understand why, but it work. I would be glad if you can understand me )